# How to disable automatic TODO comments in flutter?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I am using flutter with android studio.

Is there a way to disable TODO comments generated when overriding any method?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that and there is no reason to do that :

Overriding a `method()` calling only its `super().method()` is unnecessary regarding the dart **style linter** [Unnecessary overrides](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unnecessary_overrides.html)

So the `//TODO` is here to remind you of implementing something else than the super class do

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. 
The `TODO comment` is there because you would want to do a task inside the `overridden method`.

You can't `override` a method and not do anything in it. So the TODO indicates something needs to be done.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks, I got your point but I actually can override a method and leave it as it is!

Comment: @HassanM.Said yes you can but there will never be a reason for doing that, except making your code more boilerplate.

Comment: You can override your own abstract class method and leave it as it is. Overriding an abstract class method that comes with the language and not doing anything in it is NOT APPROPRIATE. @HassanM.Said